# Geographic size of an Eruv

Tags: halacha, shabbat, geography, eruv-chatzerot

Inspired by [Is Juneau, Alaska -- surrounded by natural barriers -- a natural eruv](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26383/is-juneau-alaska-surrounded-by-natural-barriers-a-natural-eruv)

Is there a maximum square mile or square kilometer area that may be enclosed by an Eruv? (sources)

Comment: I suspect that the size is relevant to the Juneau question, which is why I gave land-mass details, but also noted that most of the land is itself on an island, while the downtown area is in a smaller coastal area on the mainland.  I believe that there are limits for an island -- I think you need to be able to see it all from a certain distance, but I'm not sure whether that could be from a mountain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R Moshe Feinstein ([Igrot Moshe OC 1:139:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=241)) rules that according to the Ritva and Ramban the maximum size of a Reshut HaYachid (and hence the maximum size of an Eiruv) is as far as the eyes can see, which he understands, based on [Bechorot 54b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=32&daf=54b&format=pdf), to be 16 *mil* in either direction which would be 32x32 *mil* which is roughly 1000 km^2 or 250K acres. (For reference the area of Manhattan is only 87 km^2.)

Comment: Does this imply that Rav Moshe held of the Manhattan Eiruv? I'm asking out of ignorance

Comment: @Shoel I don't understand how this would imply that